# How to use WITH result table multiple times?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
DECLARE @count INT;
WITH CTE AS
(SELECT...)
SELECT @count = COUNT(ID) FROM CTE;
SELECT * FROM CTE
```

Can I use CTE table after first expression `SELECT @count = COUNT(ID) FROM CTE`? I get error `Invalid object name 'CTE'.`
I'm using SQL Server 2008.

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by multiple times? join using the sme cte or another select statement?

Comment: @J W I need one more select statement

Comment: unfortunately you can't. the `CTE` is valid only from one statement, can be join multiple times but not in another select statement.

Comment: how about creating a view for the result of `CTE`? `:)`

Comment: If you need to reuse it #temp_tables or @table_variables should be your choice.

Comment: You can use the data of a CTE in one or multiple CTEs before your final select. But if you want multiple result sets or (as in your case) assign a variable, this wont be of much help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a table variable and use it everywhere.

```
DECLARE @count INT;
DECLARE @CTE AS TABLE (<<columns>>)

INSERT INTO @CTE (<<columns>>)
SELECT ....

WITH CTE AS
(SELECT * FROM @CTE)
SELECT @count = COUNT(ID) FROM CTE;

SELECT * FROM @CTE
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't, really; the CTE only exists for the scope of a single statement. However in this case you could do this:

```
DECLARE @count INT;

WITH CTE AS (SELECT...)
SELECT * FROM CTE;

SELECT @count = @@ROWCOUNT;
```

If you need the count as part of the resultset, then you can just say:

```
WITH CTE AS (SELECT...)
SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER() FROM CTE;
```

If you need the count for other reasons, please describe them.